# For any Cantor set $C \subset R^n$ there exists a submanifold $M \subset R^{n+1}$ such that $M \cap (R^n \times \{0\}) = C$

Tags: manifolds, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds, cantor-set, submanifold

Show that for any Cantor set $C \subset R^n$ there exists a submanifold $M \subset R^{n+1}$ such that $M \cap (R^n \times \{0\}) = C$.

I think $M$ should not be transverse to $R^n \times \{0\},$ otherwise the intersection $C$ would be a manifold. This suggests that for each $p \in C \subset (R^n \times \{0\})$, the candidate manifold will only hit $p$ but not pass thorough it. For example, if $n=1$. Then for $p \in C$, $M$ on the neighborhood of $p$ would be some curves such that its vertex is $p$. However, I don't know how to rigorously construct such manifold (and am also quite dubious about its validity). Any comments will be much appreciated.

Comment: Hint: This of the graph of a smooth function.

Comment: @MoisheKohan Yes I just googled it and I think the Blancmange curve might work here. But it seems like it is not smooth

Comment: I suggest you first construct a smooth function of one real variable whose set of zeroes is a Cantor set.

Comment: Ok I know that closed subset in $R^n$ should be zeros of some smooth functions of $R^n$ by partition of unity. And the result follows easily since cantor set is closed. Thank you!